# How to get total weekend days counts grouped by month for a given month range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

How to get total weekend(sunday) counts grouped by month for a given month range in SQL Server?

For example: dates selected : 'Oct-2020' to 'Dec-2020'

| Month Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| October | 4 |
| November | 4 |
| December | 5 |

Comment: More detail. What are your tables, what query have you tried so far?

Comment: I would use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) to get an answer to this type of queries. If you have a Calendar table in your database, then it becomes a trivial query.

Comment: @Charlieface, no table, i just need counts based on date range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` and `DATENAME()` functions along with a recursive CTE such as

```
DECLARE @date1 AS DATE, @date2 AS DATE;
SET @date1 = '2020-10-01';
SET @date2 = '2020-12-31';

WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 0 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS value
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < DATEDIFF(day,@date1,@date2) 
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(day, n, @date1 ) ) AS [Month Name], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day, n, @date1 ))= 'Sunday'
 GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(day, n, @date1 ))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=223e410325e6e284fe4f372b36216100)</kbd>

If the date interval covers more than one year, then use the following code which includes the ordering also.

```
DECLARE @date1 AS DATE, @date2 AS DATE;
SET @date1 = '2020-10-01';
SET @date2 = '2021-03-31';

WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 0 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS value
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < DATEDIFF(day,@date1,@date2) 
)
SELECT DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(day, n, @date1)) AS [Year],
       DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(day, n, @date1)) AS [Month Name], 
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day, n, @date1))= 'Sunday'
 GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(day, n, @date1)),
          DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(day, n, @date1)),
          DATEPART(m, DATEADD(day, n, @date1))
 ORDER BY [Year], DATEPART(m, DATEADD(day, n, @date1))
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e322c9c536851a987527f79efc609de)</kbd>

Comment: Recursive cte is really slow for this kind of thing. Use a tally or calendar table, or Itzik Ben-Gan's tally function instead